Why does (0, o.createContext) and (0, i.AI) result in "not a function" TypeErrors during the Next.js build process?
I am currently working on a Next.js application and during the build process, I am encountering two specific TypeErrors: (0, o.createContext) is not a chainable function and (0, i.AI) is not a function. These errors occur in .next\server\chunks\586.js and .next\server\app\about\page.js respectively, affecting the successful compilation of my application.
Initially, the development server seems to run without any issues, indicating the error might be related specifically to how the production build handles certain functions or configurations.
Using edge runtime on a page currently disables static generation for that page
    Collecting page data  .TypeError: (0 , o.createContext) is not a function
    at 7291 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\chunks\586.js:104:10208)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 3647 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\chunks\778.js:1:9591)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 7928 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\FAQ\page.js:1:1296)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\FAQ\page.js:6:8310)
    at E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\FAQ\page.js:6:8349
    at t.X (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
    at E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\FAQ\page.js:6:8323
    TypeError: (0 , i.AI) is not a function
    at 3199 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:3797)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 4067 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:1290)
    at t (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at r (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:6249)
    at E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:6288
    at t.X (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
    at E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:6262
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\about\page.js:1:6315)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /FAQ
at E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1268:15
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'Error'

`
What I've Tried
Confirming that all my imports for React context and any AI-related functionalities are correctly implemented across my components.
Running the project in development mode (npm run dev), where no similar errors appear, pointing towards a complication arising specifically in the production build environment.
Checking if server-side code mistakenly includes client-side only APIs.
Expectations
My expectation was that the application would build successfully as it runs in development mode without these errors. I anticipated seamless behavior transitioning from development to build considering no errors were thrown earlier.
Can anyone provide insights into why I am seeing these errors only during the production build and suggest potential resolutions to ensure the build process completes successfully? I am using million lint could that be the cause?

I'm having this exact same issue. Did you ever fix it?
